# Exclude view from schema creation with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, view, create-table

I have an entity mapped to a view in Hibernate by specifying `@NamedNativeQuery` but the SchemaExport keeps creating create table scripts for this entity.

How can I convince it to just ignore that table/view?